# JQuery GET works only first time, second time I just get server response... why?

Tags: php, jquery

I have some JQuery where when you click on a "Add to Basket" button (it's really a link), the first time everything works as expected however click the button a second time, although the product is added to basket (database row has increased quantity), the response sent by server is outputted rather than "captured" by JQuery in the SUCCESS function.

I don't understand why this would happen, any thoughts on this?

JQuery

```
$(function() {
            $( '.button' ).click(function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var url = $( this ).children( 'a' ).attr( 'href' );

                var elem = $( this ); 
                var parent = $( this ).parent().parent(); 
                var html = parent.html(); alert( html );

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: url,
                    data: '',
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'text',
                    beforeSend: function( rs ) {
                        parent.html( '<div class="basket-item item-border" style="width:896px;text-align:center;"><p class="para"><img src="/media/images/spinner.gif" />Please wait...</p></div>' );
                    },
                    success: function( rs ) {
                        parent.html( html );

                        if( rs = 'YES' ) {
                            alert( 'Okay' );
                        } else {
                            alert( 'Something went wrong' );
                        }
                    },
                    error: function( rs, err ) {
                        if( rs.status == 0 ) {
                            alert( '--- Offline' );
                        } else if( rs.status == 404 ) {
                            alert( '404 Not Found' );
                        } else if( rs.status == 501 ) {
                            alert( '501 Internal Error' );
                        } else if( err == 'timeout' ) {
                            alert( '--- Timeout' );
                        } else {
                            alert( '--- Unknown' );
                        }
                    }
                 });
            });
        });
```

And here is a section of the HTML the JQuery works on

```
<div>
            <div class="basket-item item-border" style="width:512px;text-align:left;">
                <p class="para">

                    <img 
                        width="48" 
                        height="48" 
                        alt="Sample Soap Pack (&pound;3.99)" 
                        src="http://www.mj.local/media/images/products/generic/0929005236213037.jpg" />
                <a href="http://www.mj.local/products/sample-soap-pack/">Sample Soap Pack</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="basket-item item-border"><p>3.99</p></div>
            <div class="basket-item item-border" style="width:256px;text-align:center;">
                <p class="button"><a href="http://www.mj.local/shop/add/sample-soap-pack/">
                    <span class="add">Add to Basket</span>

                </a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The contents of the parent DIV are replaced with a "Please wait.." message and then restored, as expected so would this alter any way JQuery works? I have another JQuery working okay when swapping HTML so why now with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because on success you are replacing the html of the parent, your **.button** will be replaced, and the new .button won't have the click event binded anymore.

You could fix it by using live jQuery <1.7:

```
$(function() {
  $('.button').live('click', function() {
     //your function here
   });
});
```

or on for jquery >1.7:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".button", function(){ });
});
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking too but not sure how to overcome it.

Comment: @ElizabethQ an easy fix would be to use live or on instead of click

Comment: @ElizabethQ This is a bad accept vote... `.delegate()` is slightly more complicated but `.live()` is depreciated, performs slower and shouldn't be promoted at this point...

Comment: @Jasper I did mention the `on` for jquery > 1.7 and I added an example now.

Comment: `.delegate()` is the preferred method for jQuery Core 1.4.2 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing your `.button` element inside the callback function for the AJAX request that clicking on the `.button` element makes and when you remove the `.button` element the `click` event handler for that element is also removed. I would use event delegation so the event handler will affect all the elements currently in the DOM and ones added later (for example by an AJAX call):

Just change:

```
$( '.button' ).click(function( e ) {
```

To:

```
$(document).delegate('.button', 'click', function( e ) {
```

Here are docs for `.delegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate

Comment: Jasper, thanks very much, your suggestion works great but why does JQuery not resolve this issue it's self when we swap HTML?

Comment: That would require a lot of logic on jQuery's part (and the jQuery team is always trying to reduce the size of the framework). That logic would have to make assumptions as to whether or not you want the event bindings to persist after the DOM is altered. The main reason this isn't a part of the jQuery framework is that it could break a lot of code people have already written (expecting that when a DOM element is removed from the DOM that it's event binding are also removed)